# Get reference points base frame Tango Device

Tags: tango

I want to get x,y,z coordinates of the base frame from TangoPoseData in tango device.

```
if (pose.baseFrame == TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION
    && pose.targetFrame == TangoPoseData
    .COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE) {
    if (pose.statusCode == TangoPoseData.POSE_VALID) {
      //get base frame coordinate
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A pose represents transformation between two frames, you can't get a pose by only using one frame (the base frame in your case).